# Using Leaflet elevation profiles with multiple GeoJSON features?

Tags: leaflet

I have a GeoJson file that contains many routes, i need to show each route on an elevation profile via Leaflet.elevation plugin, in need to when i click on a route it's profile show on the elevation profile, here is my code

```
  function addData(e) {
    var el = L.control.elevation();
    el.addData(e);
    map.addControl(el);
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on ('click', function(e) {
        addData(feature)
    });
}

  $.getJSON('data/routes/network=Nwn_Lines.json', function(e) {
    Nwn = L.geoJson(e, {
      style: function(feature, layer) {
        return {color:'#0000FF', weight:3, opacity: 0};
      }, onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer.on('mouseover', function() {
          $('#Name').html("Name: "+'<strong>'+layer.feature.properties.name+'</strong>');
          layer.setStyle({color: '#FFFF00', opacity: 1});
        })
        layer.on('mouseout', function() {
          $('#Name').html("Name: ");
          layer.setStyle({opacity: 0});
        })
      }, onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three major things that prevent your code from working. You have option `onEachFeature` defined twice for `geoJSON` layer. Second definition overrides the first one. Then you call your `addData` function with `feature` parameter instead of event `e` parameter. And when adding data to control you are using event `e` parameter insetad of `e.target.layer`.

Code should look something like this:

```
var elevationDisplayed = false;
var currFeature;

var el = L.control.elevation();

function showElevation(layer) {
  if (elevationDisplayed && (currFeature === layer.feature)) {
    map.removeControl(el);
    elevationDisplayed = false;
    }
  else {
    el.clear();
    if (!elevationDisplayed) el.addTo(map);
    el.addData(layer.feature);
    currFeature = layer.feature;
    elevationDisplayed = true;
  }
};

$.getJSON('data/routes/network=Nwn_Lines.json', function(e) {
  Nwn = L.geoJson(e, {
    style: function(feature, layer) {
      return {color:'#0000FF', weight:3, opacity: 0};
    }, onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      layer.on('mouseover', function() {
        $('#Name').html("Name: "+'<strong>'+layer.feature.properties.name+'</strong>');
        layer.setStyle({color: '#FFFF00', opacity: 1});
      })
      layer.on('mouseout', function() {
        $('#Name').html("Name: ");
        layer.setStyle({opacity: 0});
      })
      layer.on ('click', function(e) {
        showElevation(e.target);
      });
    }
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

I added some simple logic that elevation control is hidden when you click on line with displayed elevation the second time.

---

After checking input geoJSON file it became clear it does not contain height data. Each point should have three coordinates: [lat, lon, height]. This geoJSON has only [lat, lon]. That's why Chrome broser throws error

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNL0.0295626108…".
```

IE11 and Firefox even do not complain.

Comment: I have tried it, but it still doesn't work.
it gives an error about: Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNL0.0671259523…".

Comment: Are you sure your `json` file has `geojson` structure? You can check it on one of online checking sites, for example http://geojsonlint.com/ or http://geojson.io/

Comment: I have double checked it on this tool, it says that "crs" line should be removed.
So i have removed it and Geojson is fine now, but it still gives an error about d3 file.
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNL0.0671259523…".

Comment: Could you provide your `geojson` file so I can check it?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2d7hmfms5w5jyfq/Nwn.geojson?dl=0

Comment: It works for me, but I have slightly different code since I'm not using `jquery`. One other thing. Your geojson file does not have height data for points, so elevation control has nothing to show.

Comment: check this sample, it is not have height data and it is working.
http://mrmufflon.github.io/Leaflet.Elevation/example/example.html

i think that the elevation control indicates elevations.

Comment: See EDIT1 to my answer. If you look at geojson data in the example you are refering to, you will see that each point has three coordinates: `[lat, lon, height]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have figured it out to me.

Comment: Now i have calculated elevations of each point in that geojson file, but i don't know how to bind/insert these elevations values as [lat, lon, height].

Comment: Put this as a new question.

Comment: I have got a separated point geojson file that contains elevation points, could we use it for showing elevation profile for line geojson?

Comment: Of course you can use it if it conatins all the info you need.

Comment: could you please help me with some sample code, i have used your code but i can't use it to get elevations from points to be applied on the linestring geojson.

Comment: I can't help you without seeing your new geojson file with elevation points.

Comment: here it the points that contains Z values
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o03txiuguo0ctix/Nwm_elevations.rar?dl=0

Comment: You won't be able to use this geojson file because it does not contain lines. Each point is separate geojson object.

Comment: So, no way to insert these Z values into coordinates in the geometry of linestring GeoJSON?

Comment: As I wrote before, this requires new question. I'm no expert in geojson.

Comment: I have created a new question already but still waiting for answer.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I will try to add these Z values into the linestring GeoJSON, but i can't insert it into geometry, coordinates [lat, long, Z] but i can add it as a property
i just need help with addData function in the code in order to the L.control.elevation can see values of elevations.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89906/discussion-on-answer-by-tomazicm-using-leaflet-elevation-profiles-with-multiple).